# Retrieving the current value from a stream; without closing it?

Tags: flutter, dart

I can't seem to get the current value of a stream without closing it.
tried stream.first, stream.last and stream.single
But my understanding is that the stream must close (or wait for a new item to be added to the sink (single)) before any of those will return anything, but i need the current value without closing the stream.

How can i do that?

ex:

```
    var streamObject = await messagesStream.last; // or first/single
    print("execution never reaches this print ...");
    var list = streamObject.data;
    list.add(msg);
    messagesSink.add(ApiResponse.completed(list));
```

edit (better overview of my problem in code):

Websocket Provider

```
    socket.on('chatmessage', (data) {
      var en = json.encode(data);
      getMessageSink.add(Message.fromJson(json.decode(en)));
    });
```

Bloc

```
  ChatBloc.withWebSocketMsgStream(Stream<Message> websocketMsgStream) {
    _messagesController =
        StreamController<List<Message>>.broadcast();
    _chatRepository = ChatRepository();

    websocketMsgStream.listen((msg) {
    var streamObject = await messagesStream.last; // or first/single
    print("execution never reaches this print ...");
    var list = streamObject.data;
    list.add(msg);
    messagesSink.add(ApiResponse.completed(list));
    });
  }
```

See some more explanation to the problem in the comments to answer provided by G3nt_M3caj

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what kind of `Stream` it is, but, assuming you have handling a network stream your code might be:

```
  // assuming it's a dynamic data stream
  //Stream<dynamic> messagesStream;
  messagesStream.listen((content) {
    print("data: $content");
  });
```

That means you have to use the method `listen` which is called every time your stream has changes by adding/getting some data.

In other scenarios (where you have to make a `Stream` by yourself) you need to use also a `StreamController` to add data to that stream. Here are some info about: https://dart.dev/tutorials/language/streams

Comment: So i have 1 Provider that handles websocket events, in that provider there is a streamcontroller where all new messages for a chat is added.

In the chat i have a Bloc that has its own streamcontroller of all messages for a chat. Im trying to add new messages from the websocket stream to bloc stream.

websocketstream<Messages>  and blocstream<List<Message>>.

the websocket stream is injected in the bloc's constructor and 'listen'ed to as your example. then i try to get the List<Message> from the bloc stream, add the new listened to msg from websocketstream to that list.

Comment: cont...

So there is no new events to listen to in the blocstream<List<Message>> to get the that data... Im probably missing something 'architectually-wise'

Comment: There isn't seen a `_messagesController.stream.add(something).` I think there needs more code to understand your scenario. However at the link on dart platform you can find all you need about streams.  :)

Comment: Cannot 'add' to a stream, but there is a `messagesSink.add(ApiResponse.completed(list));` in the Bloc

Answer (score 1):

**New syntax using for loop**

same as listen

```dart
const Stream messagesStream = ...;

await for (final message in messagesStream) {
  print(message);
}
```

you can use this syntax in list for example

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    await for (final message in messagesStream)
      if (message.isMine)
        Text(
          message,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
        )
      else
        Text(
          message,
          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
        ),
  ],
);
```